# How to change the individual frame header colors on Beamer?

Tags: beamer

I want to change the color of the frame header for a single slide in my beamer presentation.

There are a lot of questions on here regarding how to change colors in beamer but I have not found a single answer that is workable, I am looking for something simple like

```
\begin{frame}[color=red]{Frame Title}

\end{frame}
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example?

Comment: What is wrong with `\begin{frame}{\textcolor{red}{Frame Title}}`?

Comment: Frame header may contain frame title, section and subsection titles in head, and others. Hence an [mwe](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) is helpful to limit your problem to specific theme combanitions.

Comment: It looks like you are just looking for a local redefinition of the `headline` unless I missed your point. But your question lacks information to say much more